# ESP8266 current spikes influence analog sensor

Tags: esp8266

I'm using Wemos D1 mini with enabled and connected Wi-Fi and photocell connected to A0 with a 10K voltage divider.

Because of ESP8266 behavior with huge current spikes up to 400mA, photocell acts like a random signal generator.

I wonder if it's possible to eliminate those silly voltage drops/current spikes.

I've tried adding 5 parallel connected 470uF electrolytic caps as close to ESP as possible, but it didn't help so much.

Thank you for sharing your ideas

Comment: needs a schematic to clarify the problem. None of us has the schematic of your boards in our head, so helping you is impossible! Please add a schematic to your question that clarifies what you're looking at.

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxj9aybXvEBRRGEyZUgyVlZyLWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stabilize just the signal then you could add a shunt regulator just to the Photocell part of your circuit. Use a [TL431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) to regulate the voltage on the Photocell (the ref 2.5 V should be sufficient with a 390 Ohm resistor) from the 3.3 V regulator on the MCU.

[image]

If the signal still varies too much, then you could try increasing the capacitance on the 3.3 V regulator output (I assume you added your extra capacitance to the 5 V supply).